# How to enable or disable a listbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, plugins, listbox

How to enable or disable listbox control using jQuery?

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<div>
    <select size="4" name="ctl02$ddlCompensationDates" multiple="multiple" id="ctl02_ddlCompensationDates" disabled="disabled" class="chzn" style="width: 173px; display: none;">
        <option value="06/12/2015">06/12/2015</option>
        <option value="06/15/2015">06/15/2015</option>
        <option value="06/20/2015">06/20/2015</option>
        <option value="06/21/2015">06/21/2015</option>
    </select>
    <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi chosen-disabled" style="width: 173px;" title="" id="ctl02_ddlCompensationDates_chosen">
        <ul class="chosen-choices">
            <li class="search-field">
                <input type="text" value="Select Some Options" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 149px;" disabled="">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="chosen-drop">
            <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried doing the following in ASP.NET page:

```
$('#<%= ddlCompensationDates.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', false); 
$('#<%= ddlCompensationDates.ClientID %>').focus();
```

Comment: i try in asp.net page;

Comment: $('#<%= ddlCompensationDates.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', false);                       $('#<%= ddlCompensationDates.ClientID %>').focus();

Comment: I have improved the formatting of your code block and corrected grammatical errors in the content. Well formatted code is easier to read and debug. I have also added the code that you had provided in comments into the question. Always add all relevant information about the problem in the question itself. Comments can go unnoticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my issue by   using below line of code :

```
$('#<%= ddlCompensationDates.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated");
```